# When did FOX CO make photographs of this style?

Tags: 20th-century, photo-identification, images

I've got a photo I'd like to try and date:

[image]

See the edge which has a pattern and "FOX CO" in the corner:

[image]

When was this style photograph produced by the "FOX CO"?

Comment: This might help: https://www.expressnews.com/life/life_columnists/paula_allen/article/Quick-Fox-Photo-once-dominated-its-industry-10610610.php

Answer (score 2):

I have a photo with the same border which is dated February, 1929, and taken in Cuervo, New Mexico.

Comment: Interesting, I believe my photo was taken in Texas on the border with Mexico.